# Access the mail in Remote server

Tags: c#, email, outlook, mapi

Can anyone tell me how to read the inbox of another user with his profile name and password.

I used the below code to read the my inbox. it is working fine.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app = null;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._NameSpace ns = null;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.PostItem item = null;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder inboxFolder = null;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder subFolder = null;

try 
   {
   app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
   ns = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");
   ns.Logon(null,null,false, false);

   inboxFolder = ns.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
   subFolder = inboxFolder.Folders["MySubFolderName"]; //folder.Folders[1]; also works

   for(int i=1;i<=subFolder.Items.Count;i++)
   {
      item = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)subFolder.Items[i];
      Console.WriteLine("Body: {0}", item.Body);
   }
}
```

Now i need to read the inbox of another user. i used below code. But still it is accessing my inbox only. Anyone please suggest.

```
ns.Logon("anotheruser@domain.com", "password", false, true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Namespace.Logon takes the name of an existing Outlook profile, not an email address. The Password parameter does nothing.

To open another user's folder, use Namespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder. Note that the current user must have an explicit right to access that folder.

Comment: I tried by giving another user's Profile(not email address) and Password to Logon function. But it is throwing me an error "Server not found" in Logon function itself. Do i need to give server name anywhere?

Comment: A I mentioned before, Logon takes the name of the existing profile on your local machine as seen in Control Panel | Mail | Show Profiles.

Comment: Can u guide me how to read mail from server. Eg: I have a server called "\\webmail.domain.com\owa". So how to read the mails from that server. Asked Same question in link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25181899/access-the-mail-in-server

Comment: Do you mean access some user's Exchange mailbox? You can use Redemption and its RDOSession.LogonExchangeMailbox (Exchange 2000 -2010) or RDOSession.LogonHostedExchangeMailbox (Exchange 2010 - 2013)

Comment: I am not sure whether client will use Exchange. Is that possible to access the mailbox irrespective of the application they use to access mail.

Comment: It is like accessing the mail from gmail. Gmail is just for example.

Comment: No, every type of mailbox has different API - Exchange, Gmail, IMAP4, etc.